# Submitting Json to Spring MVC Controller returning jsp as ajax response string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating Spring mvc app. I am submitting JSON string to controller through AJAX. What I want is to redirect the page to different JSP page.

Right now I am returning the view from controller but instead of redirecting it is returning response to previous AJAX request.

## Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    return "powerseries";
}
```

## Javascript/Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#getData').click(function(){
            var aa=JSON.stringify(answer);
            $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "hello",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType:'json',
    data:aa,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(status){
        console.log("Entered",status);
    },
    error:function(error){
        console.log("error",error);
    }
});
        });  
});  
console.dir(answer);
```

## Browser Console

[image: Browser Console showing ajax response having jsp page]

Comment: instead of returning html from conroller return path and use window.location.href to redirect from ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using AJAX, your MVC should return a special JSON response.

eg:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
@ResponseBody
public Map hello() {
    m.put('my_redirect', 'the new url');
    return m;
}
```

then handle this response in your AJAX's handler. Use javascript's `window.location.href = resp.my_redirect;` to go to the new url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to other jsp page ,  use `redirect` inside controller method.

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
 public String hello() {
   // return "powerseries";
   return "redirect:powerseries";
}

// Add method to controller .
@RequestMapping("/powerseries")
 public String returnPowerseries() {
  return "powerseries";
}
```

or just use `$("html").html(response);` if you want to entirely change your document html.

Comment: Thanks @manikantgautam . I tried using the same. but it didn't work out.